# Redirect more than one URL from HTTP to HTTPS with the same htaccess file

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, https, server

I have the next problem. I have a web in a hosting, and i want to redirect everything to HTTPS from one htaccess file.

this are the web's that i want to redirect:

1. www.mypage.com to "https"
2. mypahe.com to "https"
3. www.mypahe.com/another.html to https://www.mypage.com/another.html

I managed to do the 2 first examples, but in the 3th redirects to https://www.mypage.com

I used this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.viveogroup.com/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're capturing URI in `RewriteRule` but aren't using it's back-reference in target. Use like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.viveogroup.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Where `$1` is the back-reference of the value you're capturing using `(.*)`